# IdentityServer4 How does oidc know where to redirect to from configuration

Tags: javascript, c#, openid-connect, identityserver4

I'm running the Javascript Client example of IdentityServer4, the configuration looks like this:

```
var config = {
    authority: "https://localhost:44350",
    client_id: "Js",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5003/callback.html",
    response_type: "id_token token",
    scope:"openid profile Api1",
    post_logout_redirect_uri : "http://localhost:5003/index.html",
};
```

The Authority points to my instance of IdentityServer4 when I click the Login button,  I am redirected to the `Account/Login` route in the project.

I'm looking every where yet I do not see where or how it knows to redirect to that route, where is the configuration for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It knows because there is a mapping with the [interaction URLs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/options.html?highlight=interaction#userinteraction) which are specified as part of the [IdentityServer Options](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/dev/src/IdentityServer4/Configuration/DependencyInjection/Options/UserInteractionOptions.cs). To configure these urls to match your controllers you can do something like this in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
    options.UserInteraction = new UserInteractionOptions
    {
        //ensure that the url strings have a leading slash
        LoginUrl = "/foo/bar",<-foo/bar maps to your controller in charge of route [foo/bar]
        LogoutUrl = "/baz"
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have the referenced in my project does it default to 'account/login' path

Comment: links seems dead